# regex replace a string match from array element with different array element

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there anyway to make something like this work...

```
for (j=0;j<arrayone.length;j++){
str1 = str1.replace(arrayone[j],arraytwo[j]);
}
```

The is of course like a pseudocode that does not work... but is there a way to do something like that?

NOTE: str1 one is regular page text and the arrays have certain words in them.
Would splitting the string into an array help?

```
str1=str1.split(" ");

str1 is regular text.
arrayone == [one, two, three]
arraytwo == [this, that, other]
```

So if you find `"one"` on the text page... replace it with `"this"`

Comment: "make it work"? depending on what you want to accomplish, this code works just fine. what are the elements of `arrayone`? literal strings, RegExp objects, or strings that represent regexes? do you want to replace the first occurrence of each element or do you want to replace them all? if you've picked the first from both my last questions, your code works as it is.

Comment: Have you tried running that code? Because to me it looks like it might do the job. Keep in mind, though, that the order of `arrayone` and `arraytwo` may influence the result (if, for instance, `str1` is `"foobarboofar"` and you want to replace `"foo"` with `"oof"` and `"foobar"` with `"zebra"`). And I don't think splitting on spaces would help much in this case.

Comment: Yes, I did try that and I thought it was not working... I'll test it again. Does anyone know how to globalize the replacements?

Comment: What's "globalize the replacements"? An example of input and expected output would help us to understand your problem better.

Comment: @gravityboy if your `arrayone` is an array of strings, use `new RegExp(arrayone[j], 'g')` as the first argument to `replace`. the only problem is, if your strings may contain regex metacharacters. then you'd need to escape these.

Comment: m.buettner said replace every occurrence... that is globalize.

Comment: This will work?    'str1.replace(new RegExp(arrayone[j], 'g'),arraytwo[j]);'

Comment: How are you guys adding the grey? I indented `4 spaces` and nothing happened. `Got it`

Comment: @gravityboy just *try* whether it will work. if it doesn't, please show us your actual input and desired output.

Comment: @m.buettner added info to question.

Answer (score 0):

The `str` variable is not a string but an array, so the code will not work.

You could perform a map function instead:

```
str1 = str1.split(' ').map(function(item) {
    var p = arrayone.indexOf(item);

    return p == -1 ? item : arraytwo[p];
});
```

You may need to shim both `Array.map()` and `Array.indexOf()` for cross-browser compatibility.